# How to change text in textbox if webbrowser url changes?

Tags: vb.net

What I have:

```
Private Sub form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

WebBrowser1.Navigate(curURL)

    While WebBrowser1.Url Is curURL
        Do
            TextBox1.Text = "1/5"
        Loop
    End While
    While WebBrowser1.Url Is curURL2
        Do
            TextBox1.Text = "2/5"
        Loop
    End While

End Sub
```

I just want to change the text in an textbox if the URL is curURL2. Is there an possibility to do it?

Greetz,
Hannir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not need the While and Do loops. All you want is a simple series of If statements. But this needs to be done in the handler for the web browser's [`Navigated` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx), not in the Load event.

```
Private Sub form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   _
                       Handles MyBase.Load

    ' When the form loads, navigate to the first URL
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(curURL)

End Sub


Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigate(ByVal sender As System.Object,           _
                                 ByVal e as WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) _
                                 Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated

    ' Check the URL that was just navigated to, and see if we find a match.
    Dim navigatedUrl As String = e.Url.ToString()
    If navigatedUrl = curURL
        TextBox1.Text = "1/5"
    Else If navigatedUrl = curURL2
        TextBox1.Text = "2/5"
    Else If ...

    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "???"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is "e.Url" here? I also get an error :/ "Error in overload resolution , because there is no accessible " = " can be called with these arguments :" - then some arguments after it.

Comment: It is the current URL, the one that was just navigated to. It is passed to the event handler in the arguments. Standard design for WinForms event handlers. But it's actually a Url object, not a String object, so it has to be converted to a string before comparing it with a string. I'm guessing that `curURL` is a string. You don't actually say.

Comment: Yes it is, sry :) Thx for ur help, it works great! U saved my day ;)